# how to send or post an array from view page to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In view page i am having an array

```
$flat=Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => LOGIN [2] => LOGIN_FIELD [3] => IF_LOGIN [4] => 20 [5] => 30 [6] => com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle [7] => LOGIN [8] => User Name [9] => 1 [10] => [11] => [12] => 21884 [13] => [14] => [15] => PASSWORD [16] => LOGIN_FIELD [17] => IF_PASSWORD [18] => 20 [19] => 40 [20] => com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle [21] => PASSWORD [22] => Password [23] => 1 [24] => [25] => [26] => 21885 [27] => [28] => [29] => 8899 )
```

how i get this array in my controller.I am using form_open() in the same view page.how i can pass this?
 i tried this:

```
echo form_open('money_c/yodlogin');?>

username:<input type="text" name="uname"><br>
passord:<input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="flat[]" value="<?php echo $flat;?>">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">

<?php echo form_close();
```

in controller:$this->input->post('flat');
but i didnt get.

Comment: How can you `echo` an array?

Comment: You can use `json_encode` in view and `json_decode` to avoid multiple elements in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need an `foreach`

```
foreach($flat as $flatVal) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="flat[]" value="<?php echo $flatVal;?>">
<?php }
```

Or even you can use [**serialize**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) like

```
<input type="hidden" name="flat" value="<?php echo serialize($flat);?>">
```

and while you are printing you have to [**unserialize**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it

```
$flatArray = unserialize($this->input->post('flat'));
```

Or even you can use [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like

```
<input type="hidden" name="flat" value="<?php echo json_encode($flat);?>">
```

and while you are printing you have to [**json_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it

```
$flatArray = json_decode($this->input->post('flat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using json_encode or serialize methods

```
<?php
echo form_open('money_c/yodlogin');?>

username:<input type="text" name="uname"><br>
passord:<input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="flat" value="<?php echo json_encode($flat);?>">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">

<?php echo form_close();
```

In Cointroller

```
$flat_str = $this->input->post('flat'); 
$flat_arr = json_decode($flat_str, true);
```